# How to pass database parameters to keycloak 20+ docker?

Tags: database, docker, keycloak

I am trying to setup containers with keycloak + postgres, but as long as the `KC_DB` en variable is set to `postgres`, then `KC_DB_HOST` nor `KC_DB_URL` seems to have any effect, and he startup fails with `can't connect to localhost:5432`.

Here is the docker-compose.yml :

```
services:
  
  db-keycloak:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - "./_me_data/db-keycloak:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak
 
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      # KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgres://db-keycloak:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_HOST: db-keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: root
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: oooo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `KC_DB_HOST` with `KC_DB_URL_HOST` (see [Docs](https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?q=db-url-host))